# Random hovering element needs to hover over specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have tried a boatload of changes to the javascript and I cannot seem to get it right. Basically the function I have failed to get is to be able to make the hovering ghost div hover over a certain div or element in the page instead of just floating wherever it wants to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
animateDiv();

});

function makeNewPosition(){

// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $(window).height() - 50;
var w = $(window).width() - 50;

var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(){
var newq = makeNewPosition();
var oldq = $('.shape').offset();
var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

$('.shape').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
  animateDiv();       
});

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

var speedModifier = 0.3;

var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

return speed;

}



$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".shape").show("slow");
 $(".coupontooltip").show("slow");


 });







$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".coupontooltip").show("slow");


 });
```

[A fiddle with the current situation](http://jsfiddle.net/vL9zjamf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it attach to certain div, you have to follow these first:

1. Pass the ***Element*** at which you want to apply the random hovering div. Therefore, `animateDiv()` should be `animateDiv(element)` where variable element is the DOM element at which you want to apply this div.
2. Take that DOM Element in consideration of animation by limiting the value of **max-min offset height and weight** of `.shape`.Use this `var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxHeight - minHeight)) + minHeight;`
3. Take ***`.shape` width and height*** in account also so that it doesn't go outside the DOM element. By Decreasing the maxHeight/maxWidth by `.shape` height/width.

Your revised `makeNewPosition(element)` will look like this:

```
function makeNewPosition(element1) {
    var minHeight = $(element1).offset().top;
    var maxHeight = $(element1).height() + minHeight - 90;
    var minWidth = $(element1).offset().left;
    var maxWidth = $(element1).width() + minWidth - 90;
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxHeight - minHeight)) + minHeight;
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxWidth - minWidth)) + minWidth;
    return [nh, nw];
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL9zjamf/9/)**

P.S. have decreased a speed little bit so the effect looks more pleasant on small div you can set it accordingly